# How to get 1 result per year

Tags: mysql, sql

This is my code currently.

```
SELECT manufacturer, model, year, units_sold_m
FROM `quick-catcher-350001.Phone_Sales.Phone` 
WHERE smartphone=TRUE
ORDER BY units_sold_m DESC
```

I would like to add a line to this to get only 1 result per year to learn what was the top selling phone of each year.

Thanks

Comment: Which MySQL version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Since MYSQL 8.0, this can be done using `ROW_NUMBER`. You can use a subquery to build the row_number grouped by year and sorted by the sold units desc and then always take the rows only with row_num = 1:

```
SELECT sub.manufacturer, sub.model, sub.year, sub.units_sold_m 
FROM 
(SELECT manufacturer, model, year, units_sold_m,   
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY year 
ORDER BY units_sold_m DESC) AS row_num  
FROM yourtable
WHERE smartphone=TRUE) AS sub
WHERE row_num = 1;
```

Please note this will show **one row per year** only, according to your requirement.

If your stated requirement is incorrect and you want to show **all entries per year** when multiple entries have the same maximum units_sold_m, you should use the `MAX` function instead:

```
SELECT manufacturer, model, year, units_sold_m
FROM yourtable
WHERE (year, units_sold_m) IN
(SELECT year, MAX(units_sold_m)
FROM yourtable
WHERE smartphone=TRUE
GROUP BY year)
ORDER BY year;
```

Please see here the difference: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=baee9b324e4580a5f1326b39791fde45)